# fibonacci recursive functor

Tags: prolog, fibonacci

I am a beginner to Prolog and i want help with this 
this functor calculate the fibonacci of a number ... first time it adds Y = 0 and Z = 1 then it calls itself wtih Y = Z and Z = Y + Z and each time it increments the value of the counter C until the counter equals to X.....
the problem is the result always is equal to 1 because prolog never executes second clause even if X not equal to M but i don't know why  .....

X: the fibonacci to be calculated
Y : the first number in fibonacci series
Z : second number in fibonacci series
C : counter with 0 as intial value
T : Y + Z

```
predicates
fib_tail(integer,integer, integer,integer, real)
clauses
fib_tail(X,Y , Z,M, T):- X=M,T = Y + Z,!.
fib_tail(X,Y ,Z, C , T):-
  T = Y + Z,
  NY = Z,
  NZ = Y + Z,
  NC = C + 1,
  fib_tail(X, NY, NZ, NC, NT).

goal
fib_tail(5 ,0 ,1 ,0, T)
```

Comment: Have you checked out this site? prolog tutorial http://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/~liberti/public/computing/prog/prolog/prolog-tutorial.html

Comment: @Ibrahim +1 for 13 points of reputation!! go ahead and keep it up :) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your second clause fib_tail has 2 flaws:

- X is never incremented
- NT is a singleton, thus doesn't 'transmit' any value to the caller.

**edit** the comment highlight that X doesn't need to be incremented, being compared against the correctly incremented C.

I think you should before try to implement the doubly recursive definition, and when that's working optimize removing the costly call.

Comment: why do i need to increment X ??

Comment: you are right, it's C that tracks the increment. My fault. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: when i change the goal to fib_tail(5 ,2 ,1 ,1, T). the result doesn't equal to 1 i think the problem because the second clause i never excuted .... do you think so??

Comment: I think that you should drop (in second rule) T=Y+Z, and replace NT (the singleton) with T, so you will get back the computed result

Comment: my reputation is 6 :( i can't vote u up ..sorry 
vote me up to increase my reputation to be able to vote u up